# Sum table's colums for every change on table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, sum

I have a table where the table datas are coming from a form. I wrote a javascript function to sum columns Value1, Value2 Value3 which are at the tfoot.

```
<table id="table1" class="table table-hover table-responsive">
   <thead>
            <tr>

              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Value1</th>
              <th scope="col">Value2</th>
              <th scope="col">Value3</th>
              <th scope="col">Info</th>
              <th scope="col">Date</th>
              <th scope="col">Delete</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody id="tbody-list">


          <tr><td>Item1</td>
                    <td>1100</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>10</td>  
                    <td>Info</td> 
                    <td>2019-02-18</td> 
                    <td>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
<tr><td>Item2 </td>
                    <td>28.00 </td>
                    <td>0.87</td>
                    <td> 0.00 </td>  
                    <td>Info</td> 
                    <td>2019-02-18</td> 
                    <td>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr><tr><td>Item3 </td>
                    <td>28.00 </td>
                    <td>0.87</td>
                    <td> 0.00 </td>  
                    <td>Info</td> 
                    <td>2019-02-18</td> 
                    <td>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr><tr><td>Item4 </td>
                    <td>28.00 </td>
                    <td>0.87</td>
                    <td> 0.00 </td>  
                    <td>Info</td> 
                    <td>2019-02-18</td> 
                    <td>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr></tbody><tfoot>
            <tr><td class="h4">TOTAL Values</td>
            <td id="val1">NaN </td>
            <td id="val2">NaN</td>
            <td id="val3">NaN </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr></tfoot>


        </table>
```

Here is my js

```
sumValues(){
    let val1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('val1').innerHTML);
    let val2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('val2').innerHTML);
    let val3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('val3').innerHTML);

    const table = document.getElementById('tbody-list');


    for(let i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++){
      console.log("works");
      val1 += parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[1]).innerHTML;
      val2 += parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[2]).innerHTML;
      val3 += parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[3]).innerHTML;
    }

    document.getElementById('val1').innerHTML = `${val1}`;
    document.getElementById('val2').innerHTML = `${val2}`;
    document.getElementById('val3').innerHTML = `${val3}`;
}
```

and this is my tfoot in html I set them 0 that initial values for val1,val2,val3 are also 0, then I can sum over it.

```
  <tfoot>
            <td class="h4">TOTAL Values</td>
            <td id="total-cal">0</td>
            <td id="total-car">0</td>
            <td id="total-fat">0</td>
            <td id="total-amount"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tfoot>
```

I dont know where is the mistake but I keep getting NaN for total values?

Another question(which is related with this question).This is my eventListener , so each time there is a new item in table, the sum function is going to be called but then I realize that when I delete an item from table this wont fire up, Is there an eventlistener that I can use which fires up for any change on table?

```
    document.getElementById('tbody-list').addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted',function(){
  const ui = new UI(); 

  ui.sumValues(); 


});
```

Comment: You should initialize val1,2 and 3 with 0 and you can try `val1 += Number(table.rows[i].cells[1]).innerText.trim());`

Answer (score 0):

You can add common class to td containing Value1, Value2 Value3 . for example all `td` having `Value1` will have class `val1`, simmilarly for `td` having Value2 and Value3

Now you `document.getElementsByClassName` that will give a collection, Then use array method to calculate the sum. To use the array method reduce , you have to convert collection to array using `Array.from`.

`innerHTML` will give the text inside the `td` and `trim` will remove any white space.

`0` in `Array.from(arr).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return acc + parseFloat(curr.innerHTML.trim())
  }, 0)` is the initial value of the `acc`, so it will be like `0+1100 +28+28+28`

```js
function doSum(arr) {
  console.log(arr)
  return Array.from(arr).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return acc + parseFloat(curr.innerHTML.trim())
  }, 0)
}


function calValues() {
  let val1Val = doSum(document.getElementsByClassName('val1'));
  let val2Val = doSum(document.getElementsByClassName('val2'));
  let val3Val = doSum(document.getElementsByClassName('val3'))

  document.getElementById('val1').innerHTML = val1Val.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('val2').innerHTML = val2Val.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('val3').innerHTML = val3Val.toFixed(2);
}
calValues()
```

```html
<table id="table1" class="table table-hover table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Value1</th>
      <th scope="col">Value2</th>
      <th scope="col">Value3</th>
      <th scope="col">Info</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Delete</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="tbody-list">


    <tr>
      <td>Item1</td>
      <td class='val1'>1100</td>
      <td class='val2'>10</td>
      <td class='val3'>10</td>
      <td>Info</td>
      <td>2019-02-18</td>
      <td>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item2 </td>
      <td class='val1'>28.00 </td>
      <td class='val2'>0.87</td>
      <td class='val3'> 0.00 </td>
      <td>Info</td>
      <td>2019-02-18</td>
      <td>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item3 </td>
      <td class='val1'>28.00 </td>
      <td class='val2'> 0.87</td>
      <td class='val3'> 0.00 </td>
      <td>Info</td>
      <td>2019-02-18</td>
      <td>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item4 </td>
      <td class='val1'>28.00 </td>
      <td class='val2'>0.87</td>
      <td class='val3'> 0.00 </td>
      <td>Info</td>
      <td>2019-02-18</td>
      <td>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td class="h4">TOTAL Values</td>
      <td id="val1"></td>
      <td id="val2"></td>
      <td id="val3"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, i have another question (which is related with this question).This is my eventListener , so each time there is a new item in table, the sum function is going to be called but then I realize that when I delete an item from table this wont fire up, Is there an eventlistener that I can use which fires up for any change on table?

    document.getElementById('tbody-list').addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted',function(){
  const ui = new UI(); 

  ui.sumValues(); 


});

Comment: that is possible, before i answer it will be better if you can think , search in the internet and come up with a plan & trust me that is very easy. i guess there will be a button in each row to delete it

Comment: There is already a delete button(which works to delete items) and I can call sum function in delete button 'click' event but then I have to call it in 'DOMNodeInserted' event. I thought maybe there is an event that fires up for any changge on table. I also tried 'change' event but didnt work.